# Seeing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined" despite following instructions to the letter

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been learning D3 over the last few days. I've tried to reduce everything I've been learning into one simple D3 example but I'm seeing the error mentioned in the title.

I'm sure it's something simple, what have I missed?

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.node {
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.link {
    stroke: #777;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
</style>
<script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

var width = 600,
    height = 300;

var graph = {
    "nodes": [  { "x": 208.992345, "y": 273.053211 },
                { "x": 595.98896,  "y":  56.377057 },
                { "x": 319.568434, "y": 278.523637 },
                { "x": 214.494264, "y": 214.893585 },
                { "x": 482.664139, "y": 340.386773 },
                { "x":  84.078465, "y": 192.021902 },
                { "x": 196.952261, "y": 370.798667 },
                { "x": 107.358165, "y": 435.15643  },
                { "x": 401.168523, "y": 443.407779 },
                { "x": 508.368779, "y": 386.665811 },
                { "x": 355.93773,  "y": 460.158711 },
                { "x": 283.630624, "y":  87.898162 },
                { "x": 194.771218, "y": 436.366028 },
                { "x": 477.520013, "y": 337.547331 },
                { "x": 572.98129,  "y": 453.668459 },
                { "x": 106.717817, "y": 235.990363 },
                { "x": 265.064649, "y": 396.904945 },
                { "x": 452.719997, "y": 137.886092 }
            ],
    "links": [  { "target": 11, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  3, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 10, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 16, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  1, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  3, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  9, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  5, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 11, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 13, "source":  0 },
                { "target": 16, "source":  0 },
                { "target":  3, "source":  1 },
                { "target":  9, "source":  1 },
                { "target": 12, "source":  1 },
                { "target":  4, "source":  2 },
                { "target":  6, "source":  2 },
                { "target":  8, "source":  2 },
                { "target": 13, "source":  2 },
                { "target": 10, "source":  3 },
                { "target": 16, "source":  3 },
                { "target":  9, "source":  3 },
                { "target":  7, "source":  3 },
                { "target": 11, "source":  5 },
                { "target": 13, "source":  5 },
                { "target": 12, "source":  5 },
                { "target":  8, "source":  6 },
                { "target": 13, "source":  6 },
                { "target": 10, "source":  7 },
                { "target": 11, "source":  7 },
                { "target": 17, "source":  8 },
                { "target": 13, "source":  8 },
                { "target": 11, "source": 10 },
                { "target": 16, "source": 10 },
                { "target": 13, "source": 11 },
                { "target": 14, "source": 12 },
                { "target": 14, "source": 12 },
                { "target": 14, "source": 12 },
                { "target": 15, "source": 12 },
                { "target": 16, "source": 12 },
                { "target": 15, "source": 14 },
                { "target": 16, "source": 14 },
                { "target": 15, "source": 14 },
                { "target": 16, "source": 15 },
                { "target": 16, "source": 15 },
                { "target": 17, "source": 16 }
            ]
};

var nodes = graph.nodes;
var links = graph.links;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr({
        "width": width,
        "height": height
    })


var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .classed("node", true)

node
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", width / 100)

var links = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .classed("link", true)

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start()

function tick() {
    node.transition().ease('linear').duration(animationStep)
        .attr({
            "cx": function(d) {return d.x},
            "cy": function(d) {return d.y},
            "r": 10     
    })

    link.transition().ease('linear').duration(animationStep)
        .attr({
            "x1": function(d) {return d.source.x},
            "y1": function(d) {return d.source.y},
            "x2": function(d) {return d.target.x},
            "y2": function(d) {return d.target.y}
    })
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The main problem was that you were referencing the cluster layout data layout before it has been generated so d3.layout.force() needed to be moved up. You were also missing the animationStep var and had a typo in a variable name. http://jsfiddle.net/qbbptchs/

Comment: I see no difference if I move the d3.layout.force() up - is this necessary?

Comment: Not if you fixed the overwrite problem mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting stems from this mistake:

```
var links = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .classed("link", true)
```

You're overwriting the variable "links" that you declared earlier. That means that when you pass "links" later on here:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start()
```

it doesn't contain your original array of source/target links, but instead it's that d3 object you made.  I think you probably meant `var link` instead of `var links`.

Once you fix that, you'll see that the variable "animationStep" is not defined before it's used in the "tick" function.

Comment: You're correct - should've been var link. Sorry, should've caught that myself. animationStep is now defined - also should've caught that. I'm now seeing the links generated onscreen but no nodes..

Comment: Updated node.transition() etc to node.selectAll("circle").transition etc to add the cx and cy properties to the circle rather than to the g element. I was sure I read somewhere that properties applied to the g element cascade to children... obviously wrong